# Combine line in regex expression

Tags: regex

Hello i would like to highlight a string where it will highlight this 2 line however is not working

Here is my string i have

```html
P<PHLEASTILL0<<THE0D0RE<J0WELL«««««««
P5021591 B9Plit
_1912238M2503033«««««««06
```

I would want to highlight P5021591 B9Plit
_1912238M2503033«««««««06 but as it stated is it separated

i have try use [A-Za-z0-9< ]{9}[A-Za-z0-9]{6}(.+)\r?\n *(.*) as a regex expression but some how is highlighting the above line

i am currently using https://www.regextester.com/ to test my regex expression

so how can i write this regex expression to highlight this 2 line in a combine method ?

Comment: whats wrong with `«\n(.*\n?.*)`

Comment: Oh thanks it work now just remove the arrow :) 

Thanks

Comment: it works with the arrow too, the arrow might be highlighted a different color but it isn't part of what is captured by the expression..... EDIT nevermind i guess that site doesn't support capturing groups

Comment: regex101.com is a much better simulator

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single capture group, and it might be more flexible to match `<` followed by 1 or more chars A-Z a-z or digits.

```
<[A-Za-z0-9]+«+\r?\n(.+\r?\n.*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `<[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match `<` and 1+ repetitions of A-Z a-z or 0-9
- `«+` Match 1+ repetitions of `«`
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.+\r?\n.*` Match the whole line with at least a single char, then match a newline and optional chars on the second line
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ubrxKK/1).